# How do I change my control or alt key to emit a space key

Tags: keyword

I have a laptop with a broken space bar and I want to map the right alt or control keys to emit a space character. 
For windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Use a program called Sharp Keys.

https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

There are also other alternative programs.

Search keyboard remapper for more results.